# Transforma arquivo .min em arquivo "normal"

Tags: javascript, css

Eu tenho um .js porem ele está .min queria saber se é possivel reverter para o formato com aqueles "tabs" e quebra de linha, para melhor visualização dos comandos

Comment: Já tentou colar em jsfiddle.net e clicar em tidy? Esse jeito é simples e rapido. Veja esse [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/m0asqtaw/), simplesmente copiei o código minificado do jquery e colei no site, apertei o tidy e ficou identado novamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uso essa http://unminify.com/

mas existem varias opções basta pesquisar "unminify" .

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Uso o http://jsbeautifier.org/